# Where do i put the .mdb database file using Jackcess..?

Tags: java, android, jackcess

This might be a ridiculous question, but I can't find an answer anywhere...

I have a Microsoft Access database called test.mdb. I use the Jackcess library to try to open it using the following code taken from official documentation [here](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/cookbook.html)

```
Database db = DatabaseBuilder.open(new File("mydb.mdb"));
```

Sounds simple enough, but where exactly do I place my "test.mdb"?!

Tried putting in the the assets folder and used
 file:///android_asset/test.mdb
but that didn't help. I still get `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 1):

You must check database file first.

1. if db exists -> open it,
2. else -> create a new one.

1.

```
 File dbfile = new File("mydb.mdb");
            public void Connect() {
                try {
```

```
                if (dbfile.exists() && !dbfile.isDirectory()) {

                    db = DatabaseBuilder.open(dbfile);


                } else {

                    int warning= JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Yeni bir veritabanı oluşturulsunmu?", "Mevcut Bir Veritabanı Bulunamadı",
                            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

                    if (uyari == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                        Create();
                    } else {

                        System.exit(0);

                    }
```

2.

```
    public void Olustur() {
            try {

                db = DatabaseBuilder.create(Database.FileFormat.V2010, dbfile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
```

This will create new db on your project folder.